# Install gem em-websocket failed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

uilding native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing em-websocket:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180102-2602-1tzoncz.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean
sh: 1: make: not found

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
sh: 1: make: not found

make failed, exit code 127

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out

Comment: environment is on debian 9

Comment: `make: not found` this means the make program is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error `make: not found`, which means the `make` program is missing.

You can fix it by running this command `sudo apt-get install build-essential`